# Cannot boot due to I/O Error: 16.04 LTS

Tags: boot, 16.04, hard-drive, upstart, fsck

I have done a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS last month. Since a **hard reset (power button held down until system powers down)**, every time I try to boot into Ubuntu, there's an I/O Error in /dev/sda7 and nothing seems to happen after the errors in the screenshot are printed.
I have tried the following:

1. Ran **e2fsck** multiple times on /dev/sda7 from 14.04 LTS live usb with combinations of `-c -p -v -y`. I could boot into 16 after the **first** run, but never again.
2. Ran **fsck** from Ubuntu recovery from GRUB. No luck.
3. Ran Ubuntu 16.04 with **upstart**. It booted till the login **prompt** (not screen). After login, `startx` results in fatal errors. I had to hard reset to shut it down.

[Failed to load Network Manager, Login Service Avahi DNS/mDNS blah, Modem Manager, Accounts Service and Thermal Daemon Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhXu9.jpg)

This never happend when I hard reset this same laptop when it was running 15.10 and 14.04 LTS.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I/O errors usually refer to physical damage to the hardware.
Hard reset goes really heavy on the hardware, so it would not surprise me that by doing it again and again (14.04, 15.10, 16.04, how many times did you do it?) finally you managed to break your hard drive! :)

My suggestion is to stop using it immediately, switch to a live session and save as much data as you can before the situation degenerates, then test the drive (via the "Disks" application) and see if you can savage it by a simple formatting (but I strongly doubt this).

If you still have problems, your last chance will probably be to change the disk and hope that you broke only that and not also something else (like the motherboard).

Comment: So I format the whole disk or only the partition that has a bad sector?

Comment: Everything would be better... But you can try to start from the partition, after you saved all the data that you don't want to loose from the whole disk (not just that partition)

Comment: How will I know if I have damaged the motherboard?

Comment: If after changing the disk you have the same problem with another one, then the problem is not the disk. Then you try to change the motherboard. It goes away? It's the motherboard :)

Comment: Formatting just the primary partition (/dev/sda7) worked. Thank you very much dadexix86!